# How to solve equation inside a loop?

Tags: equation-solving

I am new to Mathematica, so probably this question will be very basic. I have three shares (that are between 0 and 1), say $a$, $b$ and $c$. They sum up to one $(a+b+c=1)$. For every $b$ from 0 to 1, I need to find all the possible combinations of $a$ and $c$. I tried with a solve equation inside a loop, like this:

```
p = For[b = 0, b <= 1, b += 0.01,
  Solve[{a + b + c == 1 && 0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= c <= 1}, {a, c}]]
```

and it does not work because of inexact coefficients. I also tried with `FindRoot` but did not work. Do you know some way that I could use to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `all the possible combinations of a and c`. There are infinitely many for each value of `b` (of course, except when `b = 1`) since you only have one (linear) equation, but three variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general problem, i.e. of finding *all* values of $a$ and $c$ for which $a+b+c=1$ for a certain value of $b$ admits infinite solutions, as mentioned in comments.

However, your proposed code seems to imply that you can work with a *discrete resolution*, i.e. that $a,b,c$ can vary by e.g. no less than $0.01$. You can use e.g. `IntegerPartitions` to solve this problem. If you want a resolution of $0.01=1/100$, then you can use `IntegerPartitions` to find all integer triplets that sum to $1/0.01=100$, then divide each triplet by $100$:

```
IntegerPartitions[100, {3}]/100.

(* Out: {{0.98, 0.01, 0.01}, {0.97, 0.02, 0.01}, {0.96, 0.03, 0.01}, ...
     ... {0.35, 0.33, 0.32}, {0.34, 0.34, 0.32}, {0.34, 0.33, 0.33}} *)
```

This approach, however, will not produce *positional duplicates* such as `{0.01, 0.01, 0.98}` and `{0.01, 0.98, 0.01}`, which you would have obtained by your approach based on `Solve`. The approach below adds them back in:

```
1./100 Permutations /@ (PadRight[#, 3] &) /@ IntegerPartitions[100, 3] // Flatten[#, 1] &
```